# Select lines based on lines above them

Tags: text-processing, grep, pcregrep

I have a list of items, from which I want to select the names of active items:

```
item {
  status: "Active"
  properties {
    key_a: value
  }
  id: 42
  name: "Foo"
}
item {
  status: "Disabled"
  properties {
    key_b: value
  }
  id: 12
  name: "Bar"
}
item {
  status: "Active"
  id: 2
  name: "Baz"
}
```

I know that I can extract the names using capture groups with `pcregrep`:

```
$ cat list.txt | pcregrep -o1 -i '^  name: "(.*)"'
Foo
Bar
Baz
```

Using an OR expression, I can also get a list of repeated status values and names:

```
$ cat list.txt | pcregrep -o2 -i '^  (status|name): "(.*)"'
Active
Foo
Disabled
Bar
Active
Baz
```

Finally, I need to filter the names in the list based on their preceding lines. How can I do this?

The final output should be:

```
Foo
Baz
```

Comment: Why don't the `properties` have a closing brace?

Comment: I had the same question as asked by glenn jackman, what about the closing parens for the "properties" property. Secondly, you can have your result by feeding `pcregrep`'s o/p to: `sed -n 'N;s/^Active\n//p' `

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for pointing that out -- I updated the example to add the missing braces.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thanks a lot, this works. Since this seems to be the easiest solution, would you mind creating an answer with a little explanation so I can accept it?

Comment: Is this a JSON document? Why not use a JSON parser like `jq`?

Comment: @Kusalananda It's not JSON :)

Comment: Can you rely on the order as shown, where the item status appears before the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the heavy lifting has already been done by `pcregrep`, you can now pass on it' s o/p to this short `sed` snippet :

```
  sed -ne 'N;s/^Active\n//p'
```

which makes `sed` to look at 2 lines at a time, rather than the default of 1. The `N` command sticks the next line to the pattern space by separating with a newline `\n`.  Now, only if sed was able to remove the Active first line in the pattern space, is the remaining pattern space going to be printed. This is a conditional print. Otw nothing and `-n` shall ensure no autoprinting of the pattern space. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with a `grep` variation alone (admittedly I don't know `pcregrep`). Try `awk`:

```
awk '/^ *status.*Active.$/ {ACT = 1} /^ *name:/ && ACT {gsub (/"/, "", $2); print $2; ACT = 0}' file
Foo
Baz
```

Comment: pcregrepis is just grep built with Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed too

```
sed '/status.*Active/,/name/!d;/name/!d;s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the range operator of `Perl` and constrain it with a `boolean condition` to deal with nested parentheses `{}` in a block.

Normally, one would write a range in `Perl` as `/re1/ ... /re2/`, this will cause`perl` to select the blocks that begin with regex `/re1/` and end on those lines that satisfy the regex `/re2/`. We could further constrain this, to, say: `/re1/ ... /re2/ && $depth==0`.

This will cause `perl` to select only those blocks that have an additional constraint of the depth being zero. Like in this case, the block ending happens only when the `}` is found that causes the depth count to fall to zero, OTW, the block accumulation continues past this mark as well.

```
perl -lne '
    if ( /\{/ ... /\}/ && !$depth ) {
        if    ( /\{/ )                         { $depth = /^\h*item\h+\{\h*$/ ? 0 : ++$depth;     }
        elsif ( /\}/ )                         { print($name),undef($flag) if !$depth-- && $flag; }
        elsif ( /^\h*status:\h*"Active"\h*$/ ) { $flag = 1;                                       }
        elsif ( /^\h*name:\h/ )                { $name = (split /"/)[1];                          }
    }
' input.file
```